# Databricks Autoloader / writeStream: How to retry?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-autoloader

I am trying to use AutoLoader with Databricks but I am getting hit with this recommendation and error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.UnknownFieldException: 
[UNKNOWN_FIELD_EXCEPTION.NEW_FIELDS_IN_FILE] 
Encountered unknown fields during parsing: [col_name_here], 
which can be fixed by an automatic retry: true
```

I cannot find a single document using Google that captures any of this error language so I am not sure how and where I can use this supposed fix.

My code is as follows:

```
xd = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "dbfs:/mnt/temp/checkpoints/schema") \
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode","addNewColumns") \
  .option("pathGlobfilter", "20230808_*") \
  .load("/mnt/test_loc") \
.writeStream \
.format("delta") \
.outputMode("append") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/mnt/temp/checkpoints") \
.option("mergeSchema", "true") \
.option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
.toTable("dBronze.Table1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to re-run your code again and it will pickup the changes in the schema.  If it's automated job, you can configure retries on the job level (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/settings.html#configure-a-retry-policy)).

P.S. You may try to look onto [Delta Live Tables](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/index.html) - it automatically retries such tasks.